# Commandline checkout using SVN

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I am trying to automate my checkout process using SVN version 1.6.6.

When I call

```
call "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe"   checkout  URL
```

I get this message.

> SubWCRev 1.6.6, Build 17493 - 32 Bit

And when I call the following just a window pops up.

```
call "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe.exe"   checkout  URL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Documentation for the command-line options for TortoiseProc.exe](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html).

Comment: Are you sure "TortoiseProc.exe.exe" exists?

Answer (score 7):

TortoiseSVN is a program for SVN integration into the [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) shell. You get the normal command-line Subversion at `http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html`.

The command-line for checkout is (if the Subversion directory isn't in the [`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)-variable, you have to prepend the command with the path to Subversion):

```
svn checkout <url>
```

Comment: Later versions of the installer for TortoiseSVN do in fact include the command-line tools (option "command line client tools" in the "Custom Setup" screen).

Comment: @PeterMortensen where i can find SVN Tortoise commands list ? do you have any link for same ?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have (only?) installed TortoiseSVN under Windows. For using the command line efficiently, you should install the command line version of Subversion, you will find installation files at [Download Binary Packages](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) at subversion.apache.org.

If you insist to do a checkout with TortoiseSVN by using the command line, this is documented in the help of TortoiseSVN under "Appendix D. Automating TortoiseSVN".

The command you search for looks like

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:my-example /url:"http://my.server.com/svn/trunk/my-example"
```

But be aware: This will open a dialog window, and you have to manually press the "Ok" button for it to work.

Comment: Later versions of the installer for TortoiseSVN do in fact include the command-line tools (option "command line client tools" in the "Custom Setup" screen).

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN 1.7 has a command-line Subversion client. Check the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a batch file and including the checkout command would be a better option to fully automate the given scenario.

```
svn checkout [url] [path]
```

[path] is optional.